# Load CSS and JS files only to a specific module Drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I’m developing a custom module, but need that only in the page where I use this module add some CSS and JavaScript files, I know how to do this from `template.php` using a condition to specific node, but I need do it more generic, that the condition can stay in `.module` file, or some similar solution.

I have a little code in my `.module` file:

```
function mymodule_init() {
    $url = request_uri();
    $path = drupal_get_path('module', 'module_name');
    if ($url == 'xxxx') { 
        drupal_add_js($path . '/js/animations.js');
    }
}
```

This work very well, but I’m limiting, because I need know the URL where the module will used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than checking for the URL, you should add your `drupal_add_js` when you initialize the code your module will be using on a given page.

For example, if you are adding a block, you could add it to `hook_block_view`.  If you're adding a theme template, you could do it in `hook_preprocess` for that theme template.

Comment: Excellent, is a simple solution but it was able to give me an idea of how make this! Thanks.